# WebApp - How to pull diffrent range of table To multiple HTML (g script) in the same project

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I linked google sheet table to Html thru app script

two HTML page (English, More) linked to the same sheet table

everything works fine, except that I need each page to have a specific range.
what happens now is: the two HTML pages took the first code only in pull sheet.gs

For now, I need to get a different range from the same table in (sheet ID1) on each page (English.HTML, More.HTML).

also, I want a code to link the Page (Others.html) to a different sheet (sheet ID2).

pull sheet.gs

```js
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY (for page English.html)
function getData() {
  var spreadSheetId = "Sheet ID1"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Data!A3:Q"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  //exclude B&C column 
  var srcValues = range.values;
  var temp = srcValues[0].map((_, c) => srcValues.map(r => r[c])).filter((_, c) => ![2, 3].includes(c + 1));
  var values = temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c]));;
  return values;
  }


//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY (for page More.html)
 function getData2() {
  var spreadSheetId = "Sheet ID1"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange2 = "Data!C3:Q"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;

  return values;
}



//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY (for page Others.html)
 function getData3() {
  var spreadSheetId = "Sheet ID2"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange3 = "Report!A3:Q"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;

  return values;
}
```

English.Html & More.Html

```html
<!--##JAVASCRIPT Table FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->

<script>

//%%%%PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR

function preventFormSubmit() {
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
});
}
}
window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 

//HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION***

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
}
window.onload= function createdata(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getData();
}

//////////CREATE THE DATA TABLE**


function createTable(dataArray) {
if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){

//Row and hover color ***

var result = "<div> <table class='table  table-hover  '  table-layout:'fixed ' id='dtable' style='font-family: Tajawal, serif;font-size:0.8em;border:2px solid:#ddd'; >"+

"<thead   style= color:white;  border-color: inherit;  font-size:16px;  ;'>"+

//CREATE  Heading %%
//Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet***
"<th onclick='sortTable(0)'scope='col'>Name<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(1)'scope='col'>Test 1<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(2)'scope='col'>Test 2<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(3)'scope='col'>3333<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(4)'scope='col'>444<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(5)'scope='col'>555<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(6)'scope='col'>666<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(7)'scope='col'>777<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(8)'scope='col'>888<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(9)'scope='col'>999<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(10)'scope='col'>٪ 010101<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(11)'scope='col'>11<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(12)'scope='col'>٪ 12<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(13)'scope='col'>13 <i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+
"<th onclick='sortTable(14)'scope='col'>٪ 14<i class='fa fa-fw fa-sort'></i></th>"+


"</tr>"+
"</thead>";


for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
result += "<tr>";
for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
result += "<td  style='border: 1px solid #dee2e6;'>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
}
result += "</tr>";
}
result += "</table></div>";

//////////  DATA TABLE End**


var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
div.innerHTML = result;

}else{

var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
//div.empty()
div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";

}
}

</script>




 <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS** ------------------------------------------------ -->

 <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">

<!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->

</div>

 <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
```

this the code for using two html page :
Code.gs

```js
/**
 * Get the URL for the Google Apps Script running as a WebApp.
 */
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}

/**
 * Get "home page", or a requested page.
 * Expects a 'page' parameter in querystring.
 *
 * @param {event} e Event passed to doGet, with querystring
 * @returns {String/html} Html to be served
 */
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log( Utilities.jsonStringify(e) );
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('English').evaluate()
    .setTitle("Performance Efficiency");//We can set title from here
  }
  // else, use page parameter to pick an html file from the script
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate()
      .setTitle("More");//We can set title from here
;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it

on pull sheet.gs
Change   var dataRange2 to   var dataRange

```js
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY (for page More.html)
 function getData2() {
  var spreadSheetId = "Sheet ID1"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Data!C3:Q"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;

  return values;
}
```

On HTML file
change the getData to getData2 .

```js
//HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION***

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
}
window.onload= function createdata(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getData2();
}
```